# Search multiple fields in two data Frames in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames:DFA and DFB.

```
Data Table: DFA                                     DFB
Fields:     name   job        check                 name   job
            alice  analist                          alice  attendant
            bob    attendant                        carl   professor
            carl   professor                        bob    analist
            daril  analist                          daril  analist
```

If two fields are the same in both data tables a third field in DFA should receive one value:

```
if (DFA$name==DFB$name and DFA$job == DFB$job) {
DFA$check <- 1
}


Data Table: DFA                                     DFB
Fields:     name   job        check                 name   job
            alice  analist    0                     alice  attendant
            bob    attendant  0                     carl   professor
            carl   professor  1                     bob    analist
            daril  analist    0                     daril  analist
```

I can do this with the loop but found that this technique is inefficient.

```
for ( x in 1:nrow(DFA)) {
    for ( y in 1:nrow(DFB)){
        if ((as.character(DFA[x,7]) == as.character(DFB[y,5])) &&
            (as.character(DFA[x,5]) == as.character(DFB[y,3])) ){
               DFA[x,22] <- 1
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know a way to make it more elegant, faster ?
I appreciate the contributions .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be simple enough to do with base R, but here's a possible `data.table` solution which allows you to add only one column during the merge while both updating it *by reference* and in a very efficient manner using *binary join*

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(DFA), name, job)
DFA[DFB, check := 1L]
DFA
#     name       job check
# 1: alice   analist    NA
# 2:   bob attendant    NA
# 3:  carl professor     1
# 4: daril   analist     1
```

---

As per explanation. We are keying the `DFA` data set by the columns we want to merge by (in order the binary join to work). Then we are performing a *binary join* by inserting `DFB` into the `i`th argument of `DFA` and simultaneously updating the `check` column *in place only* when we are able to join using the `:=` operator.

See [here](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html) and [here](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html) for additional information.